# Where can I add a custom query to Atlassian Crucible when adding files to a code review

Tags: atlassian-crucible

I've seen on a couple of sites including Atlassian a mention of being able to add code to a review via an EyeQL query; however, nobody ever mentions where I can input this query. Is this an admin feature or is there a way an end user can write a custom query to add files to a review?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. Go to search and then advance search. An EyeQL query can then be entered. This is remarkably helpful when adding an entire directory to a review.